What is this PROFILE macro?
I am looking at some old source code (circa 1994-1996) from a long-lost time a MUD gaming.
While I review the code-base, i noticed during the "startup" (opening ports and threading), it defines a Profile macro #define PROFILE(x).
Then during the port declaration, definition and attachment, it gets used three-times only through out all of the codebase.
    PROFILE(extern etext();)
    PROFILE(monstartup((int) 2, etext);)
    PROFILE(monitor(0);)

I have looked through gcc and other documentation but have been unable to find any wisdom as to WTH is going on here with PROFILE.
Any insight?
Updated: 2024-06-11
Per conversation with @MikeKinghan, here is the makefile for perspective on why his answer is good insight
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS = -g3 -fno-builtin-log
....
dmserver : .....
    $(CC) -o ... $(CFLAGS) .... -lcrypt


The declaration and calls:
extern etext();
...
monstartup((int) 2, etext);
...
monitor(0);

are for explicitly starting and stopping program profiling under BSD systems. See old BSD man page.
Cognate system calls moncontrol and monstartup are documented in the FreeBSD man pages and can be seen as weak symbols in GLIBC under Linux:
$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | egrep '(moncontrol|monstartup)'
000000000012ce70 W moncontrol@@GLIBC_2.2.5
000000000012cef0 T __monstartup@@GLIBC_2.2.5
000000000012cef0 W monstartup@@GLIBC_2.2.5

although neither of them is in man under Linux.
The effect of the macro definition:
#define PROFILE(x)

as applied to:
PROFILE(extern etext();)
PROFILE(monstartup((int) 2, etext);)
PROFILE(monitor(0);)

is to make those profiling statements compile to nothing, i.e. to disable profiling.
Since this macro definition was used, rather than commenting out or deleting the
statements, I would expect that the macro definition is or at least was at some time
within the scope of an #ifdef/#if defined that toggled profiling, e.g.
#ifdef PROFILING
...
#define PROFILE(x) x
...
#else
...
#define PROFILE(x)
...
#endif

Assuming that sort of arrangment, if the code is compiled with preprocessor option -DPROFILING, then
the macro calls:
PROFILE(extern etext();)
...
PROFILE(monstartup((int) 2, etext);)
...
PROFILE(monitor(0);)

will appear to the compiler after preprocessing as:
extern etext(); 
...
monstartup((int) 2, etext);
...
monitor(0);

where the first two statements initiate profiling and the last one stops it. If
the code is compiled without -DPROFILING then those macro calls are empty
strings after preprocessing and the compiler sees no profiling statements at all.

you talking Technical Spec Dirty to me hehehehehe....so basically they are their to "silence" them, "should" they be triggered or called?

@GoldBishop Close but not quite. Not to silence them if they're triggered but to make them either be there or not be there according to compiletime choice to profile
or not to profile. See updated answer.

highly variabled makefile...here are the flags being passed: Generally -g3 -fno-builtin-log and specifically for the exe gcc++ -o .... lcrypt

updated OP to reflect a snippet of the makefile
